# How to verify Apk files via Google?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

### Background

Not so long ago, Google has added a feature to verify APK files via its services, so if you open an APK file via a file manager, you could verify it and only then it will start installing it in case it passed its verification process.

The user now has 2 options when opening an APK file: install directly, or verify&install.

### The question

Is there maybe a way to just verify an APK file and get the result whether it's was found ok or not?

Maybe a special Intent? Maybe using "startActivityForResult" ?

I'm not even sure which app of Google does this.